# npm install errors in angular seed

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ubuntu

I am trying out AngularJS for the first time. I thought of using the angular-seed repository as a base template for starting my own AngularJS app after completing some of the courses on [CodeSchool](http://www.https://www.codeschool.com/). After cloning the [angular-seed repository](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) to my computer I ran the following command within the angular-seed directory:

```
npm install
```

However, I get an error and I am unable to run the application using:

```
npm start
```

I followed the instructions as in the README file. However, the following ouput is shown in the terminal:

```
evert@evert-Latitude-E6530:~/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install /home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
  COPY Release/bufferutil.node
make: Leaving directory `/home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed/node_modules/bufferutil/build'

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory `/home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'

> ws@0.4.32 install /home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
make: Leaving directory `/home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed/node_modules/ws/build'

> angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall /home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed
> bower install

/home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:54
                throw err;
                ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/evert/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:634:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:502:33)
    at Object.create.all.get (/home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:35:26)
    at Object.Configstore (/home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:28:44)
    at readCachedConfig (/home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:19:23)
    at defaultConfig (/home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:11:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed/node_modules/bower/lib/index.js:16:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/evert/local/bin/node" "/home/evert/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall: `bower install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall script 'bower install'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     bower install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-seed
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-seed
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/evert/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed/npm-debug.log
evert@evert-Latitude-E6530:~/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed$
```

I have the node v6.1.0 installed with npm v3.8.9. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I followed some of the [troubleshooting](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting) tips for npm, but still had no success.

Any other help/suggestions to get this fixed and working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this command:

```
sudo npm -g install bower
```

This will install bower as global npm package under sudo privileges.

Comment: Yes, I did. The following is what I got in the terminal output: 

evert@evert-Latitude-E6530:~/AngularJS/workspace/angular-seed$ sudo npm -g install bower
/usr/bin/bower -> /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
bower@1.7.9 /usr/lib/node_modules/bower

Comment: Still getting the same errors as posted above though when I run npm install

Comment: I think I have solved my issue, yet I am not sure why I had to do this? I added your line of code to the package.json file after reading in the README file of angular-seed that "We have preconfigured npm to automatically run bower..."  

I replaced 'bower install' with 'sudo npm -g install bower' and it seems to work. I can now run the application and start up the server. 

WHY though, do I have to do 'sudo npm -g install bower'? And not just 'bower install'?

Comment: You can visit my git for simpler application https://github.com/sandeepgosavi/HelloAngular